# Get column count using Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

How can I get column count in table using Sqlite. I tried with `SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`C WHERE table_name = 'test' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = "test"` it works fine for sql but doesnt works for Sqlite. Is there any other way for getting column count. Thank you..!

Answer (score 11):

Try `pragma table_info(table_name);` which will give all the columns information-name,type etc. Refer http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html

Comment: Is there any other alternative if not pragma

Comment: I use pragma without any issues, dont know of any other way

Answer (score 1):

I tried without using pragma and it worked to get column count from table in Sqlite following is the code

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
 System.out.println(numberOfColumns);
```